# div out of container in browser resize

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css

when I resize the browser window the particular div goes out of the main container 
how to fix the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/48y2Q/1
http://jsfiddle.net/48y2Q/1/embedded/result/

```
        <section id="main" style="background-color: #646464; padding: 0px;">
            <div class="inner clearfix" style="background-color: white;">
              <span style="color: #06546a; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; background-color: white;">Defie Cloud Buisness Solutions</span>helps companies of all sizes to enhance business operation, to refine the process and optimize technology, to reduce company expenses on IT maintenance, Hardware upgrade. And more importantly, to change the way buisness operate.
              <div id="primary">
                <section class="primary">
                  <ul style="width: 800px;">
                      <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; font-size: 14px;">
                        <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png">
                           All-in-One Business Management Solutions
                      </li>
                      <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; font-size: 14px;">
                        <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png">
                        Cloud-based File Management
                      </li>
                      <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; font-size: 14px;">
                        <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png">
                        Real-Time Access from any where, any time and on any devices
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </section>
              </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant CSS here too

Comment: i think you are assigning a default width to that div. instead of hard coding a specific value, use percentage.

Comment: You have fixed width to your `ul- 800px`.

Comment: @TomWalters: this is the relevant css element.style {
margin-top: 27px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 100px;
}

Comment: @nareshkumar: can you update in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

The issue is coming from 2 separate places:

```
 //Reduce width from 100% (line 815, bootstrap) because you need left margin so this can't be 100%.   
 .row-fluid {
  width: 90%;
 }
```

also reduce margin-left from 100px

```
<div class="row-fluid marketing" style="margin-top: 27px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 100px;">
```

to

```
<div class="row-fluid marketing" style="margin-top: 27px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 20px;">
```

Comment: I don't have access to your CSS file.